# Why does show combined plots and graphics fail in CDF Player but not in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, cdf-format, cdfplayer

The question is, how might I get the following script working as a CDF demo of complex inversion in a circle? It works fine in my home edition of MMA 8 run on OS X Mavericks. When saved as a CDF file and opened with the CDF Player, it produced an error:

Show::gcomb: "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[{circleK,circleAPlot[2\ oCircA],circleBPlot[2\ oCircA],invLineGraphics[2\ oCircA],invAVGrPts[2\ oCircA],invLVGrPts[2\ oCircA],caption},labels[2\ oCircA],Axes->False,PlotRange->{xBnds,yBnds},Background->GrayLevel[1]]"

SaveDefinitions -> True has no visible effect. Normally, I would simplify for a question like this, but having scant experience with CDF files, I don't really know where to begin, and perhaps the comments and labels will help to reveal the structure of the program.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* CONSTANTS *)

radCircA = 1/4; (* Radius of A *)

oCircA = (1+I)/(4 Sqrt[2]); (* Center of A *)

radR = 1; (* Radius of K *)

q = 0; (* Center of K *)

(* PLOTTING BOUNDARIES *)

bnds = 4;

xBnds = {-bnds,bnds};

yBnds = {-bnds,bnds};

(* FUNCTIONS *)

(* THE POINT OF THE PLOT IS TO DEMONSTRATE THE BEHAVIOR OF THIS FUNCTION, Subscript[I, k](z), R = 1 *)

zInv[z_,q_,R_]:=(q Conjugate[z] + (R^2 - Abs[q]^2)/(Conjugate[z]-Conjugate[q]))

(* CONVERT COMPLEX TO VECTOR w REAL ELEMENTS *)

v[z_]:={Re[z],Im[z]};

(* CIRCLE WITH ORIGIN AT q AND RADIUS OF radR *)

circleK := Graphics[Circle[v[q],radR]];

(* CALCULATE COMPLEX POINTS OF CIRCLE A AND USE TABLE TO CREATE LIST OF POINTS *)

circleATable[centerA_] := Table[radCircA Exp[I \[Theta]]+centerA, {\[Theta], 0, 2Pi, .1}];

(* INVERT COMPLEX POINTS OF CIRCLE A BY MAPPING zInv[] TO LIST OF COMPLEX POINTS; RETURNS A LIST *)

circleBTable[centerA_] := zInv[#,q,radR]&/@circleATable[centerA];

(* MAP LISTS OF COMPLEX POINTS TO LISTS OF VECTORS *)

circleAVectors[centerA_] := v[#]&/@circleATable[centerA];

lineBVectors[centerA_] := v[#]&/@circleBTable[centerA];

(* CREATE LINE PLOTS FROM LISTS OF VECTORS *)

circleAPlot[centerA_] := ListLinePlot[circleAVectors[centerA],AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->{Blue}];

circleBPlot[centerA_] := ListLinePlot[lineBVectors[centerA],AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->{Blue}];

(* INVERSION POINTS IN A, SHOWN WITH RED DOTS AND ARROWS *)

invAngles := Range[Pi/4, 3Pi/4, Pi/8];

invACPts[centerA_] := (radCircA Exp[I (#-Pi/4)]+centerA)&/@invAngles;

invLCPts[centerA_] := zInv[#,q,radR]&/@invACPts[centerA];

invAVGrPts[centerA_] :=Graphics[{Red,Point[v[#]]}&/@invACPts[centerA]];

invLVGrPts[centerA_]:= Graphics[{Red,Point[v[#]]}&/@invLCPts[centerA]];

invLineObjs[centerA_] := {Gray, Dashed,Arrowheads[.02],Arrow[{v[0],v[#]}]}&/@invLCPts[centerA];

invLineGraphics[centerA_] := Graphics[invLineObjs[centerA]];

(* LABELS *)

labelK=Text[Style["K", Bold, 12], v[-.5-.5I]];

labelA[centerA_] := {Blue,Text[Style["A", Bold, 8], v[centerA]]};

labelB[centerA_] :={Blue,Text[Style[If[Abs[centerA] == Abs[oCircA], "B = L","B"], Bold, 8], v[zInv[centerA +radCircA Exp[I  Pi/4],q,radR]+.2+.2I]]};

labelq = Text[Style["q", Bold, 12], v[0]-{.1,.1}];

(* CONVERT TEXT PRIMITIVES TO GRAPHICS OBJECTS *)

labels[centerA_] := Graphics[{labelK, labelA[centerA], labelB[centerA],labelq}];

caption = Graphics[{Text[Style["Complex inversion of circle A in unit circle K\nto circle B or to line L if origin q of K in A\nSubscript[I, k](z) =(q Overscript[z, _] + ((R^2)-|q|^2) )/(Overscript[z, _]-Overscript[q, _]), R=1", Bold,12], v[-2.2I]]}];

(* GRAPHICS AND PLOTS COMBINED USING SHOW; LAST ITEM IN TRUMPS PREVIOUS *)

Manipulate[
Show[{circleK,circleAPlot[offset oCircA],circleBPlot[offset oCircA],invLineGraphics[offset oCircA],invAVGrPts[offset oCircA],invLVGrPts[offset oCircA],caption,labels[offset oCircA]},Axes->False,PlotRange->{xBnds,yBnds},Background->White],
{{offset,2,"origin A multiplier"}, {3,2.5,2,1.5, 1, .5, 0,-.5}}
]
```

Comment: Take a look at `SaveDefinitions`.

Comment: @Kuba, I tried SaveDefinitions before posting the program. It made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have all the functions in the Initialization section. This is the first thing Manipulate evaluates. This works. Tested it in CDF. Opened in CDF player OK.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   circleK,
   circleAPlot[offset oCircA],
   circleBPlot[offset oCircA],
   invLineGraphics[offset oCircA],
   invAVGrPts[offset oCircA],
   invLVGrPts[offset oCircA],
   caption,
   labels[offset oCircA]
   }, Axes -> False,
  PlotRange -> {xBnds, yBnds}, Background -> White],

 {{offset, 2, "origin A multiplier"}, {3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, .5, 0, -.5}},

 Initialization :>
  (
   radCircA = 1/4;(*Radius of A*)
   oCircA = (1 + I)/(4 Sqrt[2]);(*Center of A*)
   radR = 1;(*Radius of K*)
   q = 0;(*Center of K*)(*PLOTTING BOUNDARIES*)
   bnds = 4;
   xBnds = {-bnds, bnds};
   yBnds = {-bnds, bnds};

   (*FUNCTIONS*)
   zInv[z_, q_, R_] :=(q Conjugate[z] + (R^2 - Abs[q]^2)/(Conjugate[z]-Conjugate[q]));
   (*CONVERT COMPLEX TO VECTOR w REAL ELEMENTS*)
   v[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]};
   (*CIRCLE WITH ORIGIN AT q AND RADIUS OF radR*)
   circleK := Graphics[Circle[v[q], radR]];
   (*CALCULATE COMPLEX POINTS OF CIRCLE A AND USE TABLE TO CREATE LIST OF POINTS*)

   circleATable[centerA_] := 
     Table[radCircA Exp[I \[Theta]] + centerA, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi, .1}];

   circleBTable[centerA_] := zInv[#, q, radR] & /@ circleATable[centerA];
   (*MAP LISTS OF COMPLEX POINTS TO LISTS OF VECTORS*)
   circleAVectors[centerA_] := v[#] & /@ circleATable[centerA];
   lineBVectors[centerA_] := v[#] & /@ circleBTable[centerA];
   (*CREATE LINE PLOTS FROM LISTS OF VECTORS*)
   circleAPlot[centerA_] := 
     ListLinePlot[circleAVectors[centerA], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
   circleBPlot[centerA_] := 
      ListLinePlot[lineBVectors[centerA], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
   (*INVERSION POINTS IN A,SHOWN WITH RED DOTS AND ARROWS*)
   invAngles := Range[Pi/4, 3 Pi/4, Pi/8];
   invACPts[centerA_] := (radCircA Exp[I (# - Pi/4)] + centerA) & /@ invAngles;
   invLCPts[centerA_] := zInv[#, q, radR] & /@ invACPts[centerA];
   invAVGrPts[centerA_] := Graphics[{Red, Point[v[#]]} & /@ invACPts[centerA]];
   invLVGrPts[centerA_] := Graphics[{Red, Point[v[#]]} & /@ invLCPts[centerA]];
   invLineObjs[centerA_] := {Gray, Dashed, Arrowheads[.02], 
      Arrow[{v[0], v[#]}]} & /@ invLCPts[centerA];
   invLineGraphics[centerA_] := Graphics[invLineObjs[centerA]];
   (*LABELS*)
   labelK = Text[Style["K", Bold, 12], v[-.5 - .5 I]];
   labelA[centerA_] := {Blue, Text[Style["A", Bold, 8], v[centerA]]};
   labelB[centerA_] := {Blue, 
     Text[Style[If[Abs[centerA] == Abs[oCircA], "B = L", "B"], Bold, 8], 
      v[zInv[centerA + radCircA Exp[I Pi/4], q, radR] + .2 + .2 I]]};
   labelq = Text[Style["q", Bold, 12], v[0] - {.1, .1}];
   (*CONVERT TEXT PRIMITIVES TO GRAPHICS OBJECTS*)
   labels[centerA_] := Graphics[{labelK, labelA[centerA], labelB[centerA], labelq}]; 
   caption = Graphics[{Text[
    Style["Complex inversion of circle A in unit circle K\nto circle B or to line L if origin q of K in A\nSubscript[I, k](z) \
=(q Overscript[z, _] + ((R^2)-|q|^2) )/(Overscript[z, _]-Overscript[q, _]), R=1", Bold, 12], v[-2.2 I]]}
     ];

   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]